# TypeScript not inferring type from class method return value

Tags: typescript, class, type-inference

I am writing a class, and in the constructor, the class class calls one of its methods `toJSON`, and assigns the return value to an instance property:

```
class Example {
  property;
  snapshot;

  constructor(){
    this.property = 'property'

    if (Math.random() < 0.5){
      this.snapshot = this.toJSON()
    }
  }

  toJSON(){
    return {
      this: 'this',
      is: 'is',
      a: 'a',
      sample: 'sample',
      json: 'json'
    }
  }

  useSnapshot(){
    console.log(this.snapshot?.nope)
  }
}
```

As I work on this, the shape of the return value of `toJSON` may change, so I don't want to hardcode a return type.  However, I would expect typescript to infer a return type and them enforce it.  So in the above example, `this.snapshot.nope` will error, because `nope` does not exist on the return type of `toJSON`, and therefore it does not exist on `this.snapshot`.  [This typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAsAKGmhQCcB7FdYgFwE8BufQiAOzBQgAtSqG9HpgpZhCrEArsCqliACgCUuAoWhUOASwgA6EuUq1oAXmgByHRWo1j+foTUAzaDICyYVZuJhmAE1JJ50AB5oAAZNAFYFG2VVDU0WNk5uQxV1LSkAKQBlAHkAOXkogF9+Yr4lDJz8yKVCYnQqMWJmbCjCGIgALhN24wAaVugNLuMNPoGwYbAxmuUIZDR0YbnUDGnlZQArCCFhraErGdLCUv4xCHRM1nYuKnlFdcFhUgxNEFIAcxl2uKvEqgB+TTMXRyEr4QpAA) shows the expected behavior.

But in my code, the return type is never properly assigned to `snapshot` - it stays as `any` type.  The code is complex and hard to reproduce, though the above example boils down the relevant parts. However, my intellisense shows a different story.

Hovering over `toJSON` shows the correct inferred type:

[image]

Hovering over `snapshot` shows type `any`:

[image]

And throughout the code, anywhere where `MyClass.snapshot` is used, the intellisense casts it as `any`, so I don;t get any type hints, or errors if I do something incorrect with that object.  I'm not sure where to begin debugging this, as my code is a bit more complicated version of the example above. I'm using TS version 4.3.5.  Where might I begin debugging this?

Comment: That's because the variable is being initialized as type any. You cannot change a variable type.

Comment: If that were true then the example I posted would not work

Comment: Have you tried explicitly typing the `snapshot` property? `snapshot: ReturnType<TimeStep["toJSON"]> | undefined`. Either way, its not going to be possible for us to debug without a reproducible example.

Comment: Using your example when I use node typescript I don't have any type errors but when I use deno I have the type errors. IntelliSense might be your problem.

Comment: @lawrence-witt `ReturnType` was exactly what I was hoping for.  Explicitly typing `snapshot` as the `ReturnType` of `toJSON` is working perfectly.  If you post that as an answer I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, we can use `ReturnType` to dynamically acquire the return type of any function. Class members can also be accessed via a type index:

```
class TimeStep {
  snapshot: ReturnType<TimeStep["toJSON"]>;

  ...

  toJSON() {
    return {}; // implementation
  }
}
```

I don't know why your environment was not able to do this automatically, but the resultant type checking is the same either way. This is perhaps even a little more descriptive.